# Graphics in C# (.NET)

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I use this code for drawing text in a panel:

```
Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawString(...);
```

So I want to know what size the input text will be when rendered in the panel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `g.MeasureString()` to get the width of a string in the grapic context.

```
// Set up string.
string measureString = "Measure String";
Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);

// Measure string.
SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);
```

Comment: A couple of points I'd like to clean up: 1) = new SizeF(); is unnecessary here; 2) it's good practice to dispose fonts (and many other graphical objects) like stringFont.Dispose() or use "using" statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [TextRenderer.MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx) which is sometimes easier to use than MeasureString.

Comment: But is only accurate if you use TextRenderer.DrawText